Failed to install NuGet package in Visual Studio 2019
I'm working on C# WinForms project, on off-line PC and need to install several NuGet packages. I have copy of this packages on the PC.
When I try to install using NuGet Package Manager it fails for any package with similar errors:

Restoring packages for C:\Users...\GmapsForm\GmapsForm.csproj... 
at NuGet.Protocol.ServiceIndexResourceV3Provider.d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at NuGet.Protocol.ServiceIndexResourceV3Provider.d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.SourceRepository.d__16`1.MoveNext()
...

Visual Studio 2019 info:

NuGet Package Manager view with System.Data.SQLite package to be installed

NuGet Package Manager format window, just after Install button press

